# Kotlin class won't let me extend abstract class from different file

Tags: kotlin, oop, package

I am working on an object-oriented project, and I want to improve my understanding of the OOP part of Kotlin. I have the following abstract class:

```
package Objecttest

abstract class Abstractclasstest {
    abstract fun testString(s: String): String
}
```

Now I want to extend it in a new class in a different file like this:

```
package Objecttest

public class Newclasstest : Abstractclasstest() {
    override fun testString(s: String): String {
        return s
    }
}
```

but when I try compiling Newclasstest.kt, I am met with the following error message: "error: unresolved reference: Abstractclasstest".

Folder structure: 
Objecttest/ 
├── Abstractclasstest.kt 
├── Newclasstest.kt

Why is this and how can I work around it? The most important bit is why, because I want to avoid the same mistake in the future.

Comment: It depends where these two files are defined and what packages you've put them in. If they're in different packages, you need to import the class at the top of the file. The IDE provides an option to automatically do this for you if you click in the red error text and press Alt+Enter.

Comment: The structure is simple. A single folder which includes only the two files. In Java I would not have to do anything, not even define packages I think. I'm trying to figure out the Kotlin way of doing this, but have had no luck so far :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to compile `Abstractclasstest.kt` first using `kotlinc Abstractclasstest.kt` and only then compile `Newclasstest.kt` as follows: `kotlinc -cp . Newclasstest.kt`. This will search for class files in the same path as `Newclasstest.kt` on which it should already find the one corresponding to `Abstractclasstest.kt`. Or you can just compile the 2 files at the same time using `kotlinc *.kt`.

Comment: I have compiled Abstractclasstest.kt, no problem. The error occurs when I try compiling Newclasstest.kt. I tried compiling it with -cp like you said, but there was unfortunately no difference :/

Comment: Have you tried `kotlinc *.kt`? Can you please include in your answer the complete content of each file and also the organization of the files in your filesystem?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, but I have now done what you asked. Yes, I have tried kotlinc *.kt, but no luck I'm afraid

Comment: Well. No clue then. Consider using an IDE instead is my best suggestion at this point.

Comment: I usually stick to vscode, but I tried Intellij today, and I am afraid this somehow ruined a configuration of some kind

Comment: Maybe the issue is with your environment and not with the code then.